# Low Level PDF Creation - How to set page size?

Tags: php, pdf

I'm writing a PDF directly from code in PHP. I can specify the mediabox and cropbox values in the page object, but the PDF turns out really tiny and has to be zoomed in 2400% to see the page. I want to set the actual page size in inches as an absolute.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MediaBox and CropBox coordinate values are set as points (1/72 inches). For a letter sized page you have to write [0 0 612 792] (multiply your inch values with 72).

Comment: How useful you are iPDFdev. Thank you again!

Comment: I was confused because of the "cm" command in the content object... I thought it meant centimeters! I learnt that it was in fact a drawing command, haha, so the sizes make a lot more sense now.!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using a pdf framework such as [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) rather than re-inventing the wheel.

If you want to write your own implementation then I would recommend downloading FPDF anyway and seeing how the page size is set. Either that or Zend_Pdf, both have already solved your problem.

Comment: Nope, I'm doing something very specific that the frameworks cannot do. Also, I have already done it and it works very well and is very fast and efficient. But I just need to know some little details, such as how to set the page size.